# How to list files in windows using command prompt (cmd). I've tried using ' ls ' as in Linux but it shows an error?

Tags: windows, cmd, ls

When I tried to use list `ls` on a Windows command prompt, the system doesn't recognize it.  I already added `C:\Windows\System32` in the path.

Comment: `ls` is a unix command, not Windows

Comment: Since this is the first Google hit for `ls windows`: for those who don't want to learn Windows commands, I downloaded the GnuWin32 [CoreUtils package](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm) and added the `bin` dir to my `PATH`. There are lots of other good gnu utils on that site. Cheers!

Comment: `ls` is a Unix command, not Windows. But if you still want `ls` in Windows, you can download it from http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Stack Overflow is for _programming_ questions. Trivial interactive use of a CLI is not programming.

Comment: Actually, ls is also Windows PowerShell command that try to mimic unix ls.

Answer (score 438, accepted):

Use the command `dir` to list all the directories and files in a directory; `ls` is a unix command.

Comment: `echo @dir %* > %systemroot%\system32\ls.bat` will allow you to use `ls` instead of `dir`, similarly to an alias

Comment: it is  possible to make  `dir` dsplay text horizontally ?

Comment: this is helpful, just type dir in the cmd not the filename and dir.

Comment: @Webman, I was able to open dir horizontally when I opened it in the bash terminal rather than just the Windows CMD

Comment: @Webwoman To show text horizontally, you can use `dir /w`.

Comment: and "ls -al"  How does this work out in windows?

Comment: I did `echo @dir %* /OG /W > %systemroot%\system32\ls.bat`, so when I type `ls` it will display directory horizontally sorted by "folders first"

Comment: Downvote it because Windows powershell actually have ls, just not cmd.