# how to use module from github to jupyter notebook

Tags: github, module, jupyter-notebook, repository

I am a new user of python and github.

I want to use, with anaconda-jupyter on windows 10, a new repository (module) published on github ( https://github.com/jamesbowman/raytrace ).

I downloaded the zip folder and extracted it in my download folder (F:\Téléchargement\raytrace-master). , but I don’t know how to use this module with jupyter .

How can I import this module into jupyter .

I tried some method but without success

[image]

Why it is not possible to copy and paste directly a folder from my download folder (F:/téléchargement/) to a jupyter notebook folder (…/source/repos/ for example ) ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the http copy url from the Github site and use that with

`!git clone <https://github.com...>` in a jupyter notebook cell

then you can do `!ls` to check that the repository downloaded. The exclamation points mean that you can do command line commands from your notebook!

Alternatively, you could try unzipping and moving the repo to the same directory where you are running jupyter and search for it with an `!ls`

Comment: git and ls are not recognized as an internal command...

Comment: My bad. This is a windows thing. Try Dir for ls https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42727245/ls-in-cmd-on-windows-is-not-recognized. You'll need to download git if you haven't already. https://git-scm.com/download/win . (the learning curve is worth it)

Comment: I tried your  solution here :  https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-demo/5a5eb6bb04250b199a1cbb529e744075216a17a5?urlpath=lab%2Ftree%2Fdemo%2FUntitled.ipynb   . It seems to be good!

Comment: I'm not familiar with how this is hosted, but if it works, I'm glad!

Comment: Thanks for your help