# I am doing a yolov5 project my backend is done,but when i upload a image or video on front end(Flask) it is showing some error

Tags: python, project

```
 <FileStorage: 'WIN_20231016_15_38_17_Pro.jpg' ('image/jpeg')>
 [2024-02-10 13:44:28,790] ERROR in app: Exception on /detect [POST]
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\akash\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", 
 line 2525, in wsgi_app
     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   File "C:\Users\akash\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", 
 line 1822, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\akash\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1820, in full_dispatch_request
     rv = self.dispatch_request()
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   File "C:\Users\akash\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", 
 line 1796, in dispatch_request
     return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint]) 
 (**view_args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   File "C:\Users\akash\YOLOv5-Flask-master\app.py", line 26, in 
 detect
     subprocess.run("ls")
     File "C:\Users\akash\anaconda3\Lib\subprocess.py", line 548, in 
   run
       with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
     File "C:\Users\akash\anaconda3\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1026, 
  in 
  __init__
      self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
    File "C:\Users\akash\anaconda3\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1538, in 
  _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file 
  specified
  127.0.0.1 - - [10/Feb/2024 13:44:28] "POST /detect HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

I tried reinstalling Python, but didn't solve nothing.

Answer (score 0):

`ls`, which you attempt to call, is a [UNIX/Linux utility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ls), and it doesn't exist on Windows. See also: [How to list files in windows using command prompt (cmd). I've tried using ' ls ' as in Linux but it shows an error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42727245)